# MySQL IN clause: How can I get multiple rows when I use a same value multiple times?

Tags: c#, mysql, list, select, in-operator

I'm programming a C# Windows Forms Application in Visual Studio and I'm trying to get data about prices of products and the amount a user has added a product to its shopping list from my local MySQL-database into a List(int).

What I do is following:

If a user has added a product 4 times to their shopping list, I'm adding the barcode of the product 4 times to my List(int).

This is working but when I'm reading out all items of the List with the String.Join()-method into the IN-clause of my query and execute it, it only returns a row one time altough the IN-operator has the same barcode multiple times.

The following is how I'm adding barcodes to my List(int)

```
int count = 0;
List<int> barcodes = new List<int>();
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT product_barcode, amount FROM shopping_list_items WHERE shopping_list_id = " + current_shoppingListID + ";", db.connection);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

while (reader.Read())
{
    do
    {
        barcodes.Add(Int32.Parse(reader["product_barcode"].ToString()));
        count++;
    } while (count < Int32.Parse(reader["amount"].ToString()));
}

reader.Close();
```

This is how I'm executing my query and assign the values to variables:

```
MySqlCommand cmdSum = new MySqlCommand("SELECT sum(price) AS 'total', supermarket_id FROM prices WHERE barcode IN (" + String.Join(", ", barcodes) + ") GROUP BY supermarket_id;", db.connection);
cmdSum.ExecuteNonQuery();
var readerSum = cmdSum.ExecuteReader();

while (readerSum.Read())
{
    switch (double.Parse(readerSum["supermarket_id"].ToString()))
    {
        case 1:
            sumSupermarket1 = double.Parse(readerSum["total"].ToString());
            break;

        case 2:
            sumSupermarket2 = double.Parse(readerSum["total"].ToString());
            break;

        case 3:
            sumSupermarket3 = double.Parse(readerSum["total"].ToString());
            break;
     }
}
```

A simplified query just to make it simple may look like this:

```
SELECT name FROM products WHERE barcode IN (13495, 13495, 13495);
```

If the above one is my query then I want it to return 3 the same rows.

So my question now is, how can I get multiple rows altough I use a same value multiple times in the IN-clause of a MySQL-query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Q: how can I get multiple rows altough I use a same value multiple times in the IN-clause of a MySQL-query?*

A: We don't. That's not how `IN ()` works.

Note that

```
WHERE foo IN ('fee','fi','fi','fi')`
```

Is shorthand for

```
WHERE ( foo = 'fee'
     OR foo = 'fi'
     OR foo = 'fi'
     OR foo = 'fi'
      )
```

Understand what's happening here. MySQL is going to examine each row, and for each row it checks to see if this condition returns TRUE or not. If the row satisfies the condition, the row gets returned. Otherwise the row is not returned.

It doesn't matter that a row with `foo` value of `'fi'` satisfies multiple conditions. All MySQL cares about is that the condition inside the parens ultimately evaluates to TRUE.

As an illustration, consider:

```
  WHERE ( t.picked_by     = 'peter piper'
       OR t.picked_amount = 'peck'
       OR t.name          LIKE '%pickled%'
       OR t.name          LIKE '%pepper%'
        )
```

There could be a row that satisfies every one of these conditions. But the `WHERE` clause is only asking if the entire condition evaluates to TRUE. If it does, return the row. If it doesn't, then exclude the row. We don't get four copies of a row because more than one of the conditions is satisfied.

---

**So how do we get a set with multiple copies of a row?**

As one possible option, we could use separate `SELECT` statements and combine the results with `UNION ALL` set operator. Something like this:

```
SELECT p1.name FROM product p1 WHERE p1.barcode IN (13495)
UNION ALL
SELECT p2.name FROM product p2 WHERE p2.barcode IN (13495)
UNION ALL
SELECT p3.name FROM product p3 WHERE p3.barcode IN (13495)
```

Note that the result from this query is significantly different than the result from the original query.

There are other query patterns that can return an equivalent set.

---

**FOLLOWUP**

Without an understanding of the use case, the specification, I'm just guessing at what we are attempting to achieve.  Based on the two queries shown in the code (which follows a common pattern we see in code that is vulnerable to SQL Injection),

The shopping list:

```
SELECT i.product_barcode
     , i.amount
  FROM shopping_list_item i
 WHERE i.shopping_list_id = :id
```

What is `amount`? Is that the quantity ordered? We want *two* cans of this, or *three* pounds of that? Seems like we would want to multiply the unit price by the quantity ordered to get the cost. (Two cans is going to  cost twice as much as one can.)

If what we are after is the total cost of the items on the shopping list from multiple stores, we could do something like this:

```
SELECT SUM(p.price * s.amount)  AS `total`
     , p.supermarket_id 
  FROM ( SELECT i.product_barcode
              , i.amount
           FROM shopping_list_item i 
          WHERE i.shopping_list_id = :id
       ) s
  JOIN price p
    ON p.barcode = s.product_barcode
 GROUP
    BY p.supermarket_id
```

Note that if a particular `product_barcode` is not available for particular `supermarket_id`, that item on the list will be excluded from the total, i.e. we could get a lower total for a supermarket that doesn't have everything on our list.

For performance, we can eliminate the inline view, and write the query like this:

```
SELECT SUM(p.price * i.amount)  AS `total`
     , p.supermarket_id
  FROM shopping_list_item i
  JOIN price p
    ON p.barcode = i.product_barcode
 WHERE i.shopping_list_id = :id
 GROUP
    BY p.supermarket_id
```

---

If we absolutely have to rip through the shopping list query, and then use the rows from that to create a second query, we could form a query that looks something like this:

```
SELECT SUM(p.price * i.amount) AS `total`
     , p.supermarket_id 
  FROM ( -- shopping_list here
         SELECT '13495' AS product_barcode, '1'+0 AS amount 
         UNION ALL SELECT '13495', '1'+0
         UNION ALL SELECT '13495', '1'+0
         UNION ALL SELECT '12222', '2'+0
         UNION ALL SELECT '15555', '5'+0
         -- end shopping_list
       ) i
   JOIN price p
     ON p.barcode = i.product_barcode
  WHERE i.shopping_list_id = :id
  GROUP
     BY p.supermarket_id
```

Comment: Thank you very much spencer, it worked. I was stuck a couple of hours but you just solved it :) btw: with amount I am meaning the couple of times a user has added a product to its shopping list.

Answer (score -1):

You would probably be better off investigating LINQ to SQL rather than using direct SQL and injection.

You can use an inline table join to accomplish what you want:

```
"SELECT sum(price) AS 'total', supermarket_id
 FROM (select "+barcodes[0]+"as bc union all select "+String.Join(" union all select ", barcodes.Skip(1).ToArray())+") w
 JOIN prices p ON p.barcode = w.bc
 GROUP BY supermarket_id;"
```

Note: If you can name the column with the inline table alias (I couldn't test that) you could simplify the inline table generation.

Comment: Does LINQ to SQL work with MySQL? I was aware that EF did, not sure about LINQ to SQL.

Comment: @mjwills There's a number of options - see Nuget for LINQ2Db.MySQL, MySQL Connector/Net supports EF 6 and LINQ to SQL, and there are commercial products such as DevArt's. I normally use the IQ Driver included in LINQPad.